# implicit package loading in dotnet with docker

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile, rider

I have a .NET Project: `TestApp`. I can get it to run successfully using a Rider run configuration and Target framework `net5.0` (on a Mac). I am trying to containerize it with Docker.

In this case, the .csproj file for the TestApp does not explicitly name all of the packages needed; other required packages are loaded implicitly when the corresponding Projects are referenced. That is, my Project references other Projects in the same Solution.

I have generated what I think is a standard Dockerfile, according to the documentation:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestApp/TestApp.csproj", "TestApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestApp/TestApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TestApp"
RUN dotnet build "TestApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestApp.dll"]
```

When running the app from the Dockerfile, it fails on the first implicitly referenced package. In this case it is an Azure package:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.20.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8'. The system cannot find the file specified.
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.20.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8'. The system cannot find the file specified.

BUT, when I look at the container files, I can see the missing package in the /app directory:

```
/app/Azure.Core.dll
```

So, I am not sure what I'm missing here. I can add the appropriate `PackageReference` to the `TestApp.csproj` file, but I'll be chasing a lot of redundant dependencies that are already listed elsewhere in the Solution.

I thought that opening a terminal in the container and seeing what I could learn from calling `dotnet` might help, but I'm bumping into the fact that `final` doesn't have the rest of the SDK in it.

Any advice on how to troubleshoot this would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project references other projects in the same solution, then you need to copy all the .csproj files before doing `dotnet restore`. I.e.

```
COPY ["TestApp/TestApp.csproj", "TestApp/"]
```

should be

```
COPY ["TestApp/TestApp.csproj", "TestApp/"]
COPY ["Project2/Project2.csproj", "Project2/"]
COPY ["Project3/Project3.csproj", "Project3/"]
```

You only need to `restore`, `build` and `publish` the main project. It'll see the project references and include them.

Comment: Excellent — will give that a go. Thanks!

Comment: So, that fixed it, along with an addition to the `TestApp.csproj`:
`<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project2/Project2.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project3/Project3.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
`
Does that seem right?

Comment: Yes. Although I'm a little surprised it didn't already have those references.